# XSL Transform to split comma separated values

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, tags

I have a sample XML in this format:

```
<Records>
 <Record>
  <Name>Test</Name>
  <IDS>Test-1, Test-2, Test-3</IDS>
  <Type>Type1</Type>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <Name>XML</Name>
  <IDS>Test-4, Test-5</IDS>
  <Type>XMLType</Type>
 </Record>
</Records>
```

I want to extract the comma separated values from the IDs tag, such that I can distinctly set them in my output XML. So in this case, since there are 5 IDs in all, I will have 5 Records, 3 of them in one group and 2 of them in another.

Essentially, my output should be somewhat like this:

```
<Records>
 <Record>
  <Name>Test</Name>
  <ID>Test-1</ID>
 <Record>
 <Record>
  <Name>Test</Name>
  <ID>Test-2</ID>
 </Record>
 ..
 ..
 <Record>
  <Name>XML</Name>
  <ID>Test-5</ID>
 </Record>
</Records>
```

How can I split the values to generate this kind of output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a "Identity transform" based xslt-1.0  solution.
The content of  IDS is spitted by recursive calls to splitIDS.
Record/Type will be ignored because they are not in your output example.
Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore IDS in Record -->
    <xsl:template match="Record/IDS" />

    <!-- ignore Type in Record -->
    <xsl:template match="Record/Type" />


    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitIDS">
            <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="IDS" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="splitIDS">
        <xsl:param name="ids"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($ids,',')">
                <xsl:call-template name="splitIDS">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-before($ids,',')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="splitIDS">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-after($ids,' ')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                    <ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ids"/>
                    </ID>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Records">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ID>Test-1</ID>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ID>Test-2</ID>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ID>Test-3</ID>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>XML</Name>
    <ID>Test-4</ID>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>XML</Name>
    <ID>Test-5</ID>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to split the values. Now how can I change the names of the tags present inside the XML?

Say, I want to include `<Type>` but in the name of `<RecordType>`, how can I do that?

For example,

`<RecordType value="Test-1">`

Comment: Change `<xsl:template match="Record/Type"/>` to: `<xsl:template match="Record/Type" >
  <RecordType>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </RecordType>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: Yes, that will give me <RecordType>Test-1</RecordType>. How can I put that particular value inside a value attribute?

`<RecordType value="Test-1"/>`

Comment: Use `xsl:attribute` or shorter  `<RecordType value="{.}" />`

Comment: Its actually returning me the entire IDS. `value="Test-1, Test-2, Test-3"`. Also the output is coming as only 3 `<Record>`.

Comment: Finally, I want to achieve:

`<OBJECTS>
   <OBJECT>
        <ITEM title="name" value="<Value-Of-Name>"/>
  <ITEM title="id" value="<Value-Of-Split-Id>"/>
  <ITEM title="type" value="<Value-Of-Type>"/>
 </OBJECT>
 <OBJECT>
        <ITEM title="name" value="<Value-Of-Name>"/>
  <ITEM title="id" value="<Value-Of-Second-Split-Id>"/>
  <ITEM title="type" value="<Value-Of-Type>"/>
 </OBJECT>
 ..
 ..
<OBJECTS>`

So essentially, <OBJECT> will be same as <Record>.

Comment: Okay I got that, had to insert that near the $ids and use the same in the `value={$ids}`. Thank you very much for helping me out!